# vertically centered with adjustable parent heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap framework with two `col-sm-6` class columns. They are matched in height using `row-eq-height` since the adjacent column contains just a background image.

Updated code:

```css
section, .section-img {
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

 .row-eq-height {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
 }

.col-sm-6 {
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.section-content {
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="section-content">
      .... content of post ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 section-img" style="background-image:url('<?php ... image code ... ?>>
    ... image taking up all the space ....
  </div>

</section>
```

The code centers and adjusts when height increases but removes the image height (equal height of row). The image should be as tall as the column adjacent to it so the picture shows

Updated output:

[image]

Comment: are you interested in doing it 'the javascript way' ?

Comment: it looks like you're mixing techniques, but i'm no expert on this. a few ideas here: https://www.sitepoint.com/atoz-css-quick-tip-vertical/. (actually, the article is [mainly] for vertical centering, but there it is.)

Comment: anyway works for me java or otherwise. I don't understand how I'm mixing techniques. The only way this way seems to work is to have some height set on the parent. I figured min-height would expand if content made it bigger, but it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already use `flexbox` you can skip the `position:absolute, transform: translate(),...` part to center things and use `flexbox` own properties for that.

```css
.row-eq-height {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.section-content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.section-img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<section class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="section-content">
        .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
        <br> .... content of post ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 section-img" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1)">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That seems to take away the height from the 'image' column

Comment: @user3550879 If you update your question with a screen shot of how it looks and should look, I adjust my answer

Comment: @user3550879 And drop me a comment here so I get notified

Comment: @user3550879 There are no images in the screen shot making me understand how it removes the image height. Could you also add the markup you use for your images, as it matter whether you have a `div` or an `img` element

Comment: Sorry, Those color slits beside the text in the screen shots are what appears for the image. I added the image code (it's a background image pulled in from the post

Comment: @user3550879 Updated my answer

Comment: However the only thing I can't seem to add anymore is the min-height: 400px; from the original code without the image only being a tall as the content ( if content is less than 400 px hight then the image is only as tall as the text and centered - not sure if your code portrays that

Comment: @user3550879 Yes, and that's why I added a wrapper in the updated answer. When you combine the `min-height` and `align-items` on the original code, the flexbox item collapse, and that's why the wrapper is needed.

Comment: prob is with the code as is, the image does not take up the whole height of the column anymore, because the space is only as big as the text makes it. So if the content is less than 400px (ex. 200px) the image is only 200px high with a 100px space on the top and bottom

Comment: That works for the images but then the centering seems not to work for me. They align at the top

Comment: @user3550879 If you could provide a screen shot showing exactly how it _should look_, with the image and all, as as of now I can't see what you mean. For me it center in both 2 last samples where the last has an image cover the full row height.

Comment: @user3550879 And which browser do you use?

Comment: I am using Chrome mostly, and I updated my question with an updated screen shot with the code you provided. I just need the text vert centered

Comment: I figured it out! thank you had some wrong code mixed in

Answer (score 0):

You can use css display:table option, and you can control vertical align, top, middle, bottom

```
HTML

<section class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="content-tbl">
    <div class="content-tbl-cell"> Text-goes-here </div>
    <div class="content-tbl-cell"> Text-goes-here </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.content-tbl {display:table;width:100%;}
.content-tbl-cell {display:table-cell;width:50%;vertical-align:middle;padding:0 15px;}
```